# How do I compare multiple years worth of geomorph changes in a river while drawing one profile line?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, bathymetry, profile, stack

I have many years worth of DEMs of a river I'm studying.

I'm very, very new to ArcGIS (think one intro class), and learned how to use the 3D analyst tool.

What I'd like to be able to do, is to draw one profile, and from that profile line, show graphs of the DEM changes for each year.

What was previously done, was a line for each year was drawn as close as possible to original line of year previous, but it's not directly on top of previous year.

Is it possible to stack these profiles and compare multiple years in the same graph?

Comment: Use interpolate shape tool, same line different Dem every time.